# Non-matching records using SQL IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have a list of employee names and I want to select all rows with those names:

```sql
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE name IN ('Chris', 'Bob', 'Jane', 'Joe')
```

**Perhaps Jane and Joe don't exist in this table. How can I create a query that identifies items in my list that don't exist at all.**

I'm not looking for any specific format as the returned result; it can be comma separated or a list of rows with the respective unmatched names.

Comment: @PM77-1 Jane and Joe don't exist in the table. I'm trying to get a result that shows "Jane" and "Joe" not existing in this table.

Comment: @user0000001 a query returns results in rows and columns. Edit your question and explain how your expected *result that shows "Jane" and "Joe" not existing in this table* will be formed among the matching names.

Comment: If the list is relatively small you can create CTE and then `OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @forpas The expectation is already there.

Comment: A string like `'not existing in this table'` is not there in the table. It must be set explicitly as the value of a column in the results. Which column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save that list as a table and then left join it with "employees".

```
select lt.list_name, e.*
  from list_table lt
  left join employee e
    on e.name = lt.list_name;
```

this will output all the names from your list in the first column and respective data from employees table. When there is no suitable record in "employees" table, you'll see first column populated only.

There only one way I see to achieve desired result if you don't have enough right in order for creating tables - it is to use a CTE:

```
with names_list(name) as (select 'Chris' union all select 'Bob' union all ...)
select nl.name, e.*
  from names_list nl
  left join employee e
    on e.name = nl.name;
```

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Creating a virtual table might be useful here.

Comment: @user0000001 if this is a big problem (like you don't have enough priviledges), you may use a CTE. It makes query a mess, but might work if creating a table is not an option. I'll update answer in a while